# Where should I put “this afternoon” here in this sentence?

Tags: adverbs

Sentence1: If, this afternoon, it is as sunny as it is now, we will go out.

Sentence2: If it is as sunny this afternoon as it is now, we will go out.

My question is which sentence is better. Where will you place “this afternoon” here if you write the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second choice is best because *this afternoon* is acting as an adverb modifying the first *is*; there is no need to separate it from the clause where it has a clear grammatical role with a pair of commas.

Comment: Thank you, Sartin. Your answer is clear. I ve' got what you mean.